# How to change the project target in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am building a C++ project on visual studio 2017 the compiler gives this information.

```
 Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target)
```

I have windows 10 installed on the system and also in the project setting-> Configuration Property -> General.

The Target platform has been defined as windows 10.

How can i set the target to windows 10.

This is the message the compiler gives.

```
Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
1>- add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to the compiler command line; or
1>- add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
1>Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum OS version requirement is set by defining `_WIN32_WINNT` to the appropriate value, as described in [Update `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=msvc-160) with more details at  [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers).

- Either add a preprocessor definition to apply to the entire build, for example to target Windows 10 add `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00` in the VS IDE under Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Preprocessor, or `/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00` on the `cl` command line (or in the makefile).
- Or `#define` the macro(s) in a shared header.

  ```
  #include <winsdkver.h>

  // uncomment to target Win 10 19H1 or later
  // #define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN10_19H1

  // target Win 10
  #define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10

  #include <sdkddkver.h>
  #include <windows.h>
  ```

For finer-grained control over the target version, define `NTDDI_VERSION` alongside `_WIN32_WINNT`, for example `/DNTDDI_VERSION=0x0A000007 /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00` for Windows 10 19H1 or later.